# Как изменить исходный код Chromium чтобы блокировать все сайты кроме некоторых разрешенных и все фото и видео на разрешенных

Tags: c++, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

Мне нужно изменить исходный код Chromium чтобы блокировать все сайты кроме некоторых согласно списку разрешенных. Список разрешенных должен подгружаться с моего сайта. Также нужно сделать так чтобы на всех разрешенных сайтах не отображались никакие видео и картинки, т.е. ни в тегах img, ни как задние фоны в css. Или же на разрешенных сайтах отображались лишь некоторые разрешенные картинки. Исходный код Chromium для Windows я уже скачал. Подскажите пожалуйста что и в каких файлах изменить?

Comment: Это скорее похоже на заказ для биржи фриланса. Чтобы снизить стоимость имеет смысл вместо переделывания Chromium использовать локальный фильтрующий прокси, типа Fiddler.

Comment: @user7860670 Нет, это не для биржи